# css label and div on the same line

Tags: html, css

This is my html

```
<div id="restaurantInformation">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>Logo</label>
            <div class="oneInfo">
                <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" >
                    <img src="../img/logo_test.jpg" alt="Profile Avatar" style="width: 180px; height: 180px;"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>username</label>
            <div class="oneInfo">

            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the css

```
#restaurantInformation{
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
}
#restaurantInformation ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#restaurantInformation ul li label{
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#restaurantInformation ul li .oneInfo{
    width: 60%;
    float: right;
    background-color: #066ECD;
}
```

I tried to make the **label and the div** on the same line but the result is this:
[image]

what am I missing wrong please?

I already try to `float` `left` and `right`

and change the `display` to `block` and `inline-block` but the result is keep as the image.

Comment: *I tried to make the div and the div* - i think u should edit the question again :)

Comment: How do you want it to appear?

Comment: You are using `label` against its definition in HTML specs. This does not affect its rendering, but neither does it do any good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the effects of the floated elements being taken out of the regular content flow.

You can keep you float from interfering with each other by altering your CSS as follows:

```
#restaurantInformation ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: auto; /* trigger a new block formatting context */
}
```

Adding `overflow: auto` will create a new block formatting context, which means that the floated elements within the `li` will be bounded by the edges of the `li` block.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/xd7aU/

Alternatively, you can clear the floats as suggested earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `display:table` property to the `label` and add `vertical-align: middle` to bring the Label content in the middle of the box.